# Call module with multiple inputs

Tags: vba, excel, input, subroutine

I've tried finding a solution to this problem but have been unable to.

In generic form:

Module1

```
Sub Source()
Call Module2.Run
End Sub
```

Module2

```
Sub Run()
Value = 10
     Some code which uses Value as input
End Sub
```

What I want to be able to do is to be able to define multiple Values in Module1 and then run Module2.Run() with each value.

Module1

```
Sub Source()
Value = 10, 20, 30
Call Module2.Run (10)
Call Module2.Run (20)
Call Module2.Run (30)
End Sub
```

Module2

```
Sub Run()
Value = Input from Module1.Source()
     Some code which uses Value as input
End Sub
```

Or something along these lines. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters through arguments like so

```
Sub Sub1 ()
    Dim myVal as Long
    myVal = 1000
    Sub2 (myVal) 'The "Call" is not necessary
End Sub
```

```
Sub Sub2 (myVal as Long) 'This sub requires an input to run (myVal)
    MsgBox myVal
End Sub
```

Comment: The statement should read `Sub2 myVal`, as the "()" are not necessary either, unless you specifically want to evaluate the parameter being passed. Now, this does not matter when passing a long - but when passing an object could have all sorts of interesting side effects. Probably worth mentioning that calling a subroutine `Run` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for you help, worked perfectly that way. AJD, thank you for your input as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array, fill it and pass as an argument.
Avoid using names like   `Source` and  `Run` which are already used by Excel;.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sour()
    Dim arr_1d() As Variant
    arr_1d = Array("val1", "val2", "val3")
    Dest arr_1d
End Sub

Sub Dest(arr_1d() As Variant)
    Dim y As Long
    For y = LBound(arr_1d) To UBound(arr_1d)
      Debug.Print arr_1d(y)
    Next
End Sub
```